# Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<String>' to type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I get the following error:

Cannot assign value of type 'Binding' to type 'String'

How to fix it?
Please help.

```
struct TextFieldWithClear: View {
    var title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(_ title: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.title = title
        self.text = $text // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<String>' to type 'String'
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $text)
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .onTapGesture { text = "" }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Replace:

`self.text = $text`

with:

`self._text = text`

You need to inject the value of `text` into the wrapped value of `self.text`. The underscore "opens" the Binding for you to change its wrapped value. Don't need to use `$` in your initializer.

Comment: Interestingly, we have to use the generated `_text: Binding<String>`, rather than the `text` we defined.

Comment: a shame that if You choose "Generate Memberwise Initializer" it fails creating a correct inti for "Bound" vars.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct TextFieldWithClear: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $text)
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .onTapGesture { text = "" }
        }
    }
}
```